# Migrate a function from mapply to tibble rowwise

Tags: r, mapply, tibble

I'd appreciate any hints tips or incantations required to convert a user-defined-function from use with `mapply` to use with `tibble` `rowwise`.

This minimal reproducible example builds on the problem [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43809701/how-to-apply-a-complicated-user-defined-function-on-each-element-of-a-tibble).

Specifically I have a function calling `uniroot` that works fine with `mapply`.
However, it breaks when using it with a `tibble`/data-frame.

```
values <- tibble(a=1:3, b=4:6)
class(values)

f_1 <- function(a, x = x_default, b = b_default, y = y_default, ...){
  x - a
}

f_2 <- function(a, x, b, y){
  value_a   <- uniroot(f_1, lower=-b*100, upper=b * 100, extendInt="no", tol=0.0001, trace = 20, maxiter=1000, check.conv=TRUE,
                          x=x, b=b, y=y)
}

newCF <- partial(f_2, x=10 , y=15)
values %>% 
  mutate( newCF( a = values$a, b = values$b ) )

x=10
y=15
mapply( f_2, values$a, x=x, values$b, y=y )
```

the Result of mapply is:

```
> mapply( f_2, values$a, x=x, values$b, y=y )
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
root       10   10   10
f.root     0    0    0
iter       1    1    1
init.it    NA   NA   NA
estim.prec 410  510  610
```

The result using the tibble is:

```
> values %>%
+   mutate( newCF( a = values$a, b = values$b ) )
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
  Evaluation error: f() values at end points not of opposite sign.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (is.na(f.lower)) stop("f.lower = f(lower) is NA") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (is.na(f.upper)) stop("f.upper = f(upper) is NA") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
7: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
6: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4: tryCatch(.External2(C_zeroin2, function(arg) f(arg, ...), lower,
       upper, f.lower, f.upper, tol, as.integer(maxiter)), warning = function(w) w)
3: uniroot(f_1, lower = -b * 100, upper = b * 100, extendInt = "no",
       tol = tolerance, trace = 20, maxiter = 1000, check.conv = TRUE,
       x = x, b = b, y = y) at #2
2: (function (a, x, b, y)
   {
       value_a <- uniroot(f_1, lower = -b * 100, upper = b * 100,
           extendInt = "no", tol = tolerance, trace = 20, maxiter = 1000,
           check.conv = TRUE, x = x, b = b, y = y)
   })(dots[[1L]][[1L]], x = dots[[2L]][[1L]], dots[[3L]][[1L]],
       y = dots[[4L]][[1L]])
```

Comment: `rowwise()` incurs pretty severe performance penalties. I'm not abt to parse a dual question issue but look into the `purrr` package and the various "2" or "p" packages for handling iteration over 2 or more vectors/lists in a tidyverse context.

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr that directed me to the solution I've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution removes the need for the use of `partial` and is as follows:

```
library(purr)
values %>% 
  bind_cols(pmap_df(list(a=.$a, b=.$b), f_2, x=10 , y=15))
```

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Nicely done! (now the pain of waiting a few days before you can accept your own answer :-)

Comment: Yup, not sure how much longer to edit the answer, because it now seems `list(a=values$a,...)` and be abbreviated to `list(a=.$a,...)` haven't been able to get it to work yet without `bind_cols(...)` but working on that.  Thanks again for the tip.